# Webpack is not loading scripts when application is running in virtual folder

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

I have a webpack application, that is bundling the angular code into one folder:

```
|
|-index.html
|-polyfills.js
|-vendor.js
|-app.js
```

Running the application using the `webpack-dev-server` works. This is also true if I deploy it to my local IIS and call it via `http://localhost`. The issue arises, when that application is placed into a folder beneath the IIS root. So if the application is called with `http://localhost/myApp/` it is returning a 404 for all assets. (`GET http://localhost/polyfills.js 404 (Not Found)`)

At first I checked the generated html output in the index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```

Since HTML and scripts are on the same relative path, this should be correct.

After that, I changed the `output.publicPath` to `"/"`, so now the config and my generated HTML looked like this:

```
output: {
        path: helpers.root('./dist'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js',
        publicPath: "/"
    },

<script type="text/javascript" src="/polyfills.js"></script>
```

This changed nothing.

I have no control on to where this small application gets deployed and how it is called, so I need to make sure all files load up correctly, no matter if they are physically located in the web applications root folder or a subfolder. What do I need to change in my `webpack.config.js` in order to achieve this?

**Edit**
As asked for in the comments, here is the generated index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>

        <base href="/">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid fill">
            <div class="row ml-0 mr-0 fill">
                <div class="col pl-0 pr-0">
                    <my-app>The application is starting up...</my-app>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post your full index.html

Comment: @Amit: the template or the generated one?

Comment: As I assumed, it's the `<base ...>` element that breaks your relative links. Remove that and your issues would be resolved

Comment: @Amit removing the base element breaks the angular application.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "breaks the angular application", but I assume you no longer get 404s, right?

Comment: Well, the application does no longer work, because angular relies on the base tag. So technically no 404's because there is no application

Comment: You wrote you're getting 404 for static script references (via script tags). That has nothing to do with angular... Without the base tag these scripts are found and loaded (check your dev tools). Perhaps you also have other problems

Comment: Angular is relying on this base tag. I remove it - Angular stops working. Of course this has to do with it. I can't just delete mandatory dependencies. But that brings me to the idea of dynamically setting it on application start up. That might help.